# Aspnet Compiler is compiling my aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the aspnet_compiler compiler program as part of the automated build procedure for a website. We have a website project and the build step generates the assembily for the project for the release build. However it generates these dlls in such a way that the aspx pages reference those at the moment randomly named assembilies. So my question is how would I modify this process to allow me to swap the dll's without updating the entire site. Also we're using nant at the moment for the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aspnet merge tool allows all the dlls to be merged into one explictly named assembily and updates the aspx and ascx files to reflect the appropriate assembily.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the -u option? The reference is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(VS.80).aspx.

Comment: Yes I have, however I think what i'm looking for is the aspnet_merge tool. Thanks anyhow.